# Aurelia compose

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

Quick question regarding Aurelia's `<compose>` element.  I had hoped to use it to insert custom elements as form controls, like this:

```
<!-- Loop through form controls -->
<div class="form-group" repeat.for="control of controls">
  <label><span t="${control.label}"></span></label>
  <compose view-model="resources/elements/${control.type}/${control.type}" 
    value.bind="control.value" data.bind="control.data" placeholder.bind="control.placeholder"></compose>
</div>
```

However, it's starting to look like the `<compose>` element is limited to only accepting `model`, `view-model` and `view` parameters.  Is that correct?  What's the best way to pass parameters like `value`, `data`, `placeholder` to my custom elements based on `control.type`?

**Edit with my Solution:**

In the end, it appears that Aurelia's `<compose>` only works with `view`, `view-model` and `model` attributes.  My solution is to pass all data **(can be multiple items passed as a single object)** like this:

```
<compose view-model="resources/elements/${control.type}/${control.type}" 
         model.bind="{'control': control, 'model': model, 'readonly': readonly}">
</compose>
```

What I *did* find interesting is that when you use `model.bind`, you don't need to use the `@bindable` decorator to receive the parameters.  They're available immediately in the view.

Comment: I also just learned from Ashley Grant that you can't use the `@bindable` parameter with `<compose>`, and that if you have a view-only element, the view is connected to the outer scope, but if you have a view-model, you need to pass via `model.bind`.

Comment: _What I did find interesting is that when you use model.bind, you don't need to use the @bindable decorator to receive the parameters. They're available immediately in the view._


**Is this still true?** I can't seem to find a way for Aurelia to bind the `model` properties to the viewmodel, without actively assigning them myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using model.bind?

```
<!-- Loop through form controls -->
<div class="form-group" repeat.for="control of controls">
  <label><span t="${control.label}"></span></label>
  <compose view-model="resources/elements/${control.type}/${control.type}"
    model.bind="control"></compose>
</div>
```

Then the view-model would have access to `value`, `data` and `placeholder` from its `model` property.

Answer (score 2):

The `<compose>` has access to the outer scope, so you don't need to bind anything. This should work:

**Usage**

```
<compose view-model="resources/elements/${control.type}/${control.type}"></compose>
```

**HTML**

```
<template>${propertyFromParent}</template>
```

Running example https://gist.run/?id=8bb9c5503b4bbb7923a3a4c9e804c656

Comment: Is this scope only available from within the `bind()` method or at all times?

Comment: all times after `bind`, I think

Comment: Fabio, I've tried this out and it simply doesn't work.  `bind() { console.log("EwTextbox bind():", this); }` only shows `__observers__` and `__proto__` and does not include any data from the parent.  `this.control` is undefined.

Comment: The above would work if you added `model="control"` to your `<compose>` tag.  Thanks for your contribution because it helped me with the big picture solution, which I added to my question edit.

Comment: @LStarky The `<compose>` has access to the outer scope, there's no need to use `model.bind`. However, the data is not accessible in the `bind()` method like I said. I was incorrect about that part, sorry. You can still use the property in the view though. See https://gist.run/?id=8bb9c5503b4bbb7923a3a4c9e804c656